# How do I format my Regex to work for highlighting Concatenated string fields in a google sheet if it matches all letters in user input field

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with data like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| G,B,R | W,R,R |
| G,B,B | R,B,R |

And a user input field where a user can put eg:
R,B

I would like the cells in columns A and B to be coloured green if all the letters in the user field are in the column field. If the column field has extra letters it should still return true and duplicates should be ignored (B,B,R = B,R).

```
=REGEXMATCH(Join("",Unique((SORT(Transpose(Split(B2, ",")))))), "^" & Join("",Unique((SORT(Transpose(Split($B$27, ",")))))))
```

Works but has issues with eg G,B,R as the G gets sorted in between B and R and it causes the regex to not match.

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bq2rwwU8fLbnxa9RmF9k-MKSkmfwbm1r2KmMa_2jeww/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't solve this problem using regex,
here's a solution that uses the [`SEARCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154) function:

```cpp
=SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(SPLIT($B$27,", "),B2))
```